# For the function $f(x,y,z)= xyz$ how close to the point $(0,0,0)$ should one take the point $(x,y,z)$ in order to make $|f(x,y,z)-f(0,0,0)|<0.008$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> For the function
>   $$f(x,y,z)= xyz$$
>    how close to the point $(0,0,0)$ should one take the point $(x,y,z)$ in order to make $|f(x,y,z)-f(0,0,0)|<0.008$?

here is my solution:

after substitution in the absolute value inequality we get
$|xyz|<0.008$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sqrt {x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}}<0.008$

but for $x,y,z <1$

$\sqrt {x^{2}y^{2}z^{2}} < \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}$
And If we choosed the distance to be less than $\delta = 0.008$ the condition will hold.

the solution of the book is $\delta = 0.2\sqrt{3}$

my questions are :

Is my solution correct?

how to obtain the solution of the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the solution of the book you may use GM-AM:

- $\sqrt[3]{abc}\leq \frac{a+b+c}{3}$

$$|xyz| = \sqrt{x^2y^2z^2} \stackrel{GM-AM}{\leq}\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}{3^3}} \stackrel{!}{<}0.008 = 0.2^3$$

Now, isolate $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$:
$$\sqrt{\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}{3^3}} <0.2^3 \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} < \left(0.2^3\sqrt{3^3} \right)^{\frac{1}{3}}=0.2\sqrt{3}$$

So, $\delta =0.2\sqrt{3}$ does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct however if you choose a cube with center in (0,0,0) and faces parallel to coordinate planes of side 0.2 and then you calculate the radius of the inscribed sphere you get the answer of the book. How to say: your answer is right but you can stay

> more far
>   from the origin.